# If default value in indexing is 0 why Python is not considering it in colon ":" by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Consider this one, if we are using slicing in python we have to pass three arguments in it `[START:END: STEP]` and if we don't want to insert index value in it they will consider by default in it like `[0:-1:1]`.

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE:

PUTTING START INDEX VALUE:

```
s="DEEPAK"
print(s[0:5])
OUTPUT:
DEEPA
```

WITHOUT START INDEX VALUE:

```
s="DEEPAK"
print(s[:5])
OUTPUT:
DEEPA
```

Now my question is why in this example this logic is not working properly?

```
s="0123456789"
print(s[:-5:-5])
OUTPUT:
9


s="0123456789"
print(s[0:-5:-5])
OUTPUT:
```

Comment: The defaults depend on whether the step is positive or negative.

Comment: For readable reason, don't use too complex INDEX and STEP.

Comment: the default value is -1 if step is negative